# window.close equivalent in Phonegap with InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I open a new page with `window.open("apphelp.html", "_blank", "location=no")`, and then it shows me a new window with my page. At the end of this page, I would like to put a "close button" so the user can come back to where they came from. I tried that with `window.close()` but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue, I am having trouble with the same thing.

Comment: No but I'll try again tomorrow.

Comment: I have tried href="javascript:history.go(-1); with the var ref = window.open(encodeURI(url), '_self', 'location=no'); and it closes the window and returns to the index file of my app, not just shutting down from where I opened it, that would be better. I´ll see if I find something else. I read that with my code you should be able to use ref.close(); But I haven´t been able to make it work yet.

Comment: I think that history.back() and history.go(-1) reload the html, so it woudn't keep it states..

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I use a workaround... 
Since the inAppBrowser can be closed only with the back button or trough javascript. I display a close button from serverside that will change the current url firing also the event 'loadstop' letting to use the .close() method, in this way only the child browser will be closed, your app will remain in the same state.

For example my server display a webpage with a close button, something like this:

```
<a href="/mobile/close">Close</a>
```

in my client side javascript (the Phonegap app):

```
var ref = window.open(encodeURI(url), '_blank', options);
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {        
    if (event.url.match("mobile/close")) {
        ref.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: What if you don't control what's returned by server?

Comment: Is there a clearer example somewhere? Or, another approach? I cannot get this to work.  For example, where exactly does that code go in PhoneGap? Do you need to have a real page that is called (not "mobile/close")?

Comment: I have this idea formatted for Ionic and NgCordova here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31793577/122183

Comment: @user1452893 so it's kind of hack. You create a link to a well-defined (potentially fake) URL and register an event listener which is launched every time navigation occurs inside the IAB. Inside the listener you check what kind of navigation happened, and if it's the magic link, you close the IAB.

Answer (score 6):

I transform for multi platform support like this：

**in the third page html and js**

```
closeBrowser(){
    if(history.length==1){
        window.open('mobile/close');
    }else{
        history.back();
    }
}



<a href="javascript:;" onclick="closeBrowser()">Close</a>
```

**in my client side javascript (the Phonegap app):**

```
var ref = window.open(encodeURI(url), '_blank','location=no');
 ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
     if (event.url.match("mobile/close")) {
         ref.close();
     }
 });
```

thanks the first floor!