# Phonegap: Simple way to listen for a page and close InAppBrowser to return to index.html

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

I've tried a half dozen examples without any luck.

I want to put a "Close" link on page(s) that will close the InAppBrowser and return the user to the app's index.html page. Seems simple, right?

I do have access to the pages where the link will be placed.

I can create links that point to an empty page that can be used to trigger the close on a loadstart or loadstop—whichever is best.

For example, I can create a page such as http://somewhere.com/CloseIAB.html

Not even sure if that's necessary since examples that have used that approach have failed.

Here's what I need to know:

Exactly which code do I need and where do I place it in the index.html for my app?

I've wasted hours trying to get this to work.

I'm using Build.

Thanks!

Comment: inAppBrowser itself has a close button at the top toolbar, isn't it sufficient ?

Comment: Thanks for the note. Yes, I' aware but hat is not desired because of design goals.

Comment: what about talking about the dozen examples you tried so we don't tell you to use one of them?

Comment: Fair enough, here's one post that has a couple of approaches that "worked". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666258/phonegap-build-open-external-page-in-inappbrowser-or-childbrowser-with-no-tool/15701122#15701122 

I could get the ref.close() to fire from the link but it hoses the normal back button functionality. The hardware back button in Android closes the browser—I cannot lose that.BTW I said "half dozen ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a custom event? Something like this (untested):

```
var ref = window.open("www.mypage.com",'_blank','location=no');
ref.addEventListener('closeiab', function() { ref.close() });
```

and in your www.mypage.com (assumes jquery):

```
$('myclosebtn').on('click', function() { $(document).trigger( "closeiab", [ ] );
```

Comment: Thanks for the note. I cannot see how this changes the ref.close() behavior which is what seems to be causing the problem. It is likely isolated to IAB's treatment of Android's hardware back button—seems hard coded to close the browser and not go back in history (even when there is some). Will give it a try though.

Comment: Thanks again but no joy with that.