# Cordova 3.0 InAppBrowser, no nav bar and no button caption

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I'm on Windows XP and I develop for Android with Cordova/Phonegap 3.0.

I've installed InAppBrowser like this:
- I've opened a command window in my project folder
- I did :

```
$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
$ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.core.inappbrowser
```

- and I've added :

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

in app/res/xml/config.xml.

First question. How can I be sure that InAppBrowser is installed ?

I've put in my HTML code this link :

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com','_blank','location=yes','closebuttoncaption=back');">open</a>
```

This link works but I have no address bar and no button 'back'.
Did I miss something ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Ok, I'm stupid... The second line ($ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.core.inappbrowser) remove the plugin...
So, now I only use the first line and the plugin is installed properly.

But I've still a problem. When I use:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com','_blank','location=yes','closebuttoncaption=back');">open</a>
```

It works fine: adress bar and button (with 'Done' as caption instead of 'back') are present.
But when I do (location=no):

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com','_blank','location=no','closebuttoncaption=back');">open</a>
```

The link opens the page but without button.
Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3):

The [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) method accepts 3 arguments, the last is an optional comma separated string of features. So you want:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com','_blank','location=no,closebuttoncaption=back');">open</a>
```

See also https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.

Answer (score 1):

In Android you have the Back-button only if you set `location='yes'`, in iOS the back-button is always present in the inAppBrowser.

However, you can modify the inAppBrowser.java file in your /platforms/android/src/org/...
Search for the line `toolbar.addView(edittext);` and comment it (I found it in line 566)

Hope I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

This guy's answer fixed your exact (2nd) problem for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596554/826308

It lets you specify location=no but still get the DONE button.

I maintain my own copy of inappbrowser (for other reasons) and just pushed up this change in case you find it useful/easier: http://goo.gl/Pk4MzR

Answer (score 0):

First question: you must check in your project.
And : Did I miss something ?
You try put code:

```
window.open('http://www.example.com','_blank','location=yes','closebuttoncaption=back');
```

in onDeviceReady(), InAppBrowser will have address bar.
That because you call InAppBrowser open when device not ready.