# Show done button inappbrowser phonegap

Tags: android, html, cordova, inappbrowser

How can I show the done button when I open a link(page) using inappbrowser in android and phone gap 3.4

I installed the inappbrowser plugin, and this how my link looks:

```
<a onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_blank);">Google</a><
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/','_blank', 'location=yes,closebuttoncaption=Done');`

This will do the wonder.

Comment: hi did you figure out how to show done button on Android at the end?

Comment: **Update - Jan 2018:** My PR to implement a native Android "Done" button in the footer has now to been merged to the official inappbrowser plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47636289/777265