# How to close InAppBrowser itself in Phonegap Application?

Tags: javascript, cordova, inappbrowser

I am developing `Phonegap` application and currently i am using `InAppBrowser` to display external pages. On some of the external pages I place a close button and i want to close the InAppBrowser itself. because InAppBrowser displays these pages that is why the reference of it is not accessed on itself to close it and Please do not suggest me to use ChildBrowser Plugin.

```
window.close(); //Not Worked for me
or  
iabRef.close();  //Also not Worked for me because iabRef is not accessible on InAppBrowser. It is created on Parent Window
```

Some of the Android device and iOS device display a Done Button to close it. As well as the iPad also display the Done button. but in Case of Android tablet there is not any kind of button to close it.

**UPDATE** :-

Here is my full code :-

```
var iabRef = null; 
function iabLoadStart(event) {
}
function iabLoadStop(event) {
}
function iabClose(event) { 
    iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);      
    iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop); 
    iabRef.removeEventListener('exit', iabClose); 
}
function startInAppB() {
    var myURL=encodeURI('http://www.domain.com/some_path/mypage.html');
    iabRef = window.open(myURL,'_blank', 'location=yes');    
    iabRef.addEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
    iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
    iabRef.addEventListener('exit', iabClose);
}
```

Comment: pls show your rest of the code where u opened the iInAppBrowser

Comment: Why don't you close it using the Back button from the navigation bar ?

Comment: When InAppBrowser display the page there are some links so user can redirect to other link that is why the back button is not suitable for me to close.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var win=window.open( "myurl", "_blank");
win.addEventListener( "loadstop", function(){
       var loop = window.setInterval(function(){
           win.executeScript({
                   code: "window.shouldClose"
               },
               function(values){
                   if(values[0]){
                     win.close();
                     window.clearInterval(loop);
                   }
               }
           );
       },100);
   });
```

In your called window, simply do:

```
window.shouldClose=true
```

When you want to close it

Comment: Thank you so much  @Torsten Simon . Do you think we can pass parameters values[1],values[2] etc from site to app. Thanks

Comment: Well, I did it by simply doing JSON.stringify(object_in_site); and doing var object=JSON.parse(values[0]); inside the app. This of course only works for Serializable data (like strings and numbers)

Comment: I see but how can execute it? After window.shouldClose=true or before? Also localStore didn't worked for me so JSON is only hope.

Comment: @PieroAlberto yes, you're right, but the method is often overriden, see https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009164/timed-popup-with-phonegap-cordova-inappbrowser

Answer (score 6):

There's a solution provided in this blog post:
[cross window communication with cordova's inappbrowser](http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-12-23/cross-window-communication-with-cordova%27s-inappbrowser)

Essentially, you could use `executeScript()` from the parent window to the InAppBrowser instance over and over (once or twice a second, for example), to check whether a value in the IAB has been set. Pressing the "close" button in IAB could set such a variable.

When the parent window discovers that the variable has been set in the IAB, the parent window uses the IAB reference to `close()` it.

Answer (score 5):

There is a SO post here that describes how to do this.

You basically have to get a reference to the inapp browser by calling window.open and hook into the loadstop event. In the loadstop event check to see if the url contains a predefined path (like mobile/close - but could be anything) and then call call close.

Here is the post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15981972/54805