# How to close phonegap/cordova InAppBrowser without using the close button

Tags: cordova, phonegap, mobile-application, inappbrowser

In my phonegap app, I open with InAppBrowser an external link (it correctly works) with:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(completeUrl, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

I need to close the opened link when a certain actions is made by the user. I know I can close it with

```
var b = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(completeUrl, '_blank', 'location=yes');
b.Close();
```

but this is on my app side, I need something similar on external link side. For example, is it possible to have the instance reference on the external link side? I think no, right?

With "location=yes" I have a confortable close button on the top, so this can be a solution, but I'd like to close it when the user finishes to use the external link, without using the native close button.

Is it possible?

UPDATE
What did I try?
1) From [window.close equivalent in Phonegap with InAppBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191793/window-close-equivalent-in-phonegap-with-inappbrowser/15981972#15981972) 
For example my server display a webpage with a close button, something like this:

```
<a href="/mobile/close">Close</a>
```

in my client side javascript (the Phonegap app):

```
var ref = window.open(encodeURI(url), '_blank', options);
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {        
    if (event.url.match("mobile/close")) {
        ref.close();
    }
});
```

2) From https://stackoverflow.com/a/50047473/819161

```
var win=window.open( "myurl", "_blank");
win.addEventListener( "loadstop", function(){
       var loop = window.setInterval(function(){
           win.executeScript({
                   code: "window.shouldClose"
               },
               function(values){
                   if(values[0]){
                     win.close();
                     window.clearInterval(loop);
                   }
               }
           );
       },100);
   });
```

In your called window, simply do:

```
window.shouldClose=true
```

When you want to close it

3) A dumb window.Close() from the called page

Nothing of my attempts worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to close the InAppBrowser window by itself, you can either use the `loadstart` or the `message` event listeners.

Check details and full examples here:
[How to close InAppBrowser window in Cordova by itself](https://www.andreszsogon.com/how-to-close-inappbrowser-window-in-cordova-by-itself/)