# Timed popup with PhoneGap/Cordova InAppBrowser?

Tags: javascript, cordova, popup, phonegap, inappbrowser

I'm using PhoneGap (Apache Cordova) with the InAppBrowser plugin (cordova-plugin-inappbrowser). In order to display a popup window, I'm using the following function:

```
function popup(url) {
  var win = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_blank", "location=no");
  win.addEventListener("loadstop", function() {
    var loop = window.setInterval(function() {
      win.executeScript(
        {code: "window.shouldClose"},
        function(values) {
          if(values[0]) {
            win.close();
            window.clearInterval(loop);
          }
        }
      );
    }, 200);
  });
}
```

What I really need is a function whose spec is:

```
function Popup(url, maxTimeToWaitIfResponseIsSlow)
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found an answer after some research and testing. Here is the modified function, with "double defense" in the client side:

```
function popup(url) {
  var elapsed = 0;
  var loadstopFired = false;
  var win = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_blank", "location=no");
  setTimeout(function() {if (!loadstopFired) win.close();}, 2000);
  win.addEventListener("loadstop", function() {
    loadstopFired = true;
    var loop = window.setInterval(function() {
      elapsed += 200;
      win.executeScript(
        {code: "window.popupStatus"},
        function(values) {
          if (values[0]=="closed") { win.close(); window.clearInterval(loop); }
          else if ((values[0]!="loaded") && (elapsed>2000)) { win.close(); window.clearInterval(loop); }
        }
      );
    }, 200);
  });
}
```

While the server side (the url called) looks like:

```
...
<body onload="window.popupStatus='loaded';">
  ...
  <img src="close.png" onclick="window.popupStatus='closed';" />
  ...
</body>
...
```

Any comment appreciated.