# impossible to close inAppBrowser window

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I can open my window, and do a lot of things inside of it, for example login via Linkedin  or Facebook. But I cannot close it to return to my app.

1/ I tried to catch events to track the url and close the window when the url contains a particular keyword. But the event is never fired. I never have any alert.

```
    var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no');

    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event)
    {
        alert(event.url);
    });

    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) 
    {
        alert(event.url);
    });
```

2/ So I tried to find a way to check ref.location.url from the first window every n seconds. But ref.location.url doesn't exist. I don't see a way to access the inapp current url from the parent window.

3/ I had the idea to give a name to the inapp window. But the inappbrowser plugin doesn't allow to give a name to the window to open. So the parent window cannot check the url of the child window that way as well.

4/ I tried to ask the child inapp window to close : cordova doesn't want a javascript to close the current window.

```
 self.close();  => cannot
 window.close(); => cannot
```

5/ I tried to revert to cordova.js 2.9.0-0-g83dc4bd , it didn't work as well.

So, I can open a pop up inside my app and use third parties Oauth but then I'm stuck inside this pop up and I have no way to return to my app.

I checked almost everything I could find in the internet and I absolutely don't see how to do now.

I use cordova.js 3.5 Android build , and I install inappbrowser with

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

Everything is standard, cordova.js is correctly loaded, and I can see in the logs InappBrowser is correctly used when I call it.

```
  08-08 16:20:20.594: D/InAppBrowser(8496): target = _blank
```

Errr... Help?

:)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191793/window-close-equivalent-in-phonegap-with-inappbrowser/15981972#15981972

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could find a way to solve this problem. It's weird and biased. But as I see I am not the only one, I'm writing here my solution and the way I could solve that bug.

First, I added another listener :

```
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) 
{
    if (debug) alert('exit');
});
```

Then, I used the inject script functionality and I called it every 5 seconds;

```
function  getStateSecondWindow()
{
    ref.executeScript(
        {code: "localStorage.getItem('loginOauth')"},
        function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    );
}

setInterval(getStateSecondWindow, 5000);
```

At that stage, I could see something weird in the logs  : the first call to  getStateSecondWindow was blocked. But then /everything/ started to work. I suddenly had all my event listeners working correctly. It was like I had a jam somewhere and the  executeScript() just unblocked everything.

This solution worked for my 4 projects. The behaviour was the same for each of them.

In case the event had problems again, I used a double system to check my second page and find a way to close it at the right moment : in the second page, I used the local storage to set the value of my var : 
localStorage.setItem( "loginOauth", 'OK');

In my first page, I used the execute script to go to read that local storage :

```
function getStateSecondWindow() {
        ref.executeScript(
            {code: "localStorage.getItem('loginOauth')"},
            function(data)
            {
                if (data=='OK')
                {
                    //do what I need to do
                    ref.close();
                } 
            }
        );
```

With this system, I was not dependent of the (sometimes not) firing event. It works even if the page in the inappBrowser window comes from another server :  as the javascript is interpreted in the second window, we are in the same domain where the original localStorage was made (no crossbrowsing problem).

So this is how I could go thought the inAppBroswer not firing events and find a way to close the second window when needed. Hope it helps :)