# inAppBrowser does not close

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, inappbrowser

I am working on a phonegap app using jquery mobile. I need to open a page from some website do perform some action. I am using in app browser for it. It opens the required page successfully but on pressing close button (there's a X symbol on top right) it does not close. 
To check whether even is being triggered or not I added

```
    ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {alert(event.type);
```

This is producing alert, so I think There is not any problem in event.

The other solution That i tried from here
[mobile/close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191793/window-close-equivalent-in-phonegap-with-inappbrowser/15981972#15981972)

My code that opens inAppBrowser is here
[Github source](https://github.com/mycomputerak47/MIS-android/blob/master/home.html)

Since I am continuously tring solutions there might be changes in code but I will comment them, So my trials will be their.

**When I click X**, The screen blinks (or i say it's like you turn over a page in book), or it's like there are two same inAppBrowser windows. One gets closed on clicking X and other is still there.

I found somewhere that on clicking done it gets closed but there is not any done button. 
This is screenshot of inAppBrowser [Screen shot from my android mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCo7d.jpg)

Comment: you are using a very old version of the plugin, so it might be a bug. Update to the latest version and try again

Comment: I skipped version of plugin as i used only
              <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
in comfig.xml

Comment: that's the old id, so you get the old plugin, you have to use cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `loadstop` event handler here to close InAppBrowser.

```
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
  if (event.url.match("mobile/close")) {
   ref.close();
  }
});
```